# graph avoiding cycle of length 4

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

let $G$ be a simple graph on $n$ vertices such that $G$ has no cycle of length $4$. show that $e(G)\le \frac{n}{4}(1+\sqrt{4n-3})$ where $e(G)$ denotes the number of the edges of the graph $G$.

Comment: Posting questions in the imperative like this is generally considered impolite. Please refer to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question .

Comment: It might be of interest for you to think about graphs which have cycles of all lengths (pancyclic) graphs as well as those which are missing a cycle of exactly one length (almost pancyclic) - see:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancyclic_graph  for a discussion of these ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I included a proof of what you want in a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74897/small-cycles-in-an-undirected-graph) of mine where I asked for a tighter bound if the graph avoids also cycles of length 3: (I use the convention $m:=e(G)$)

> I try to show if $G$ has no subgraph $C_4$, then $m \leq \frac{n}{4}(1+\sqrt{4n-3})$. We can consider the amount $k$ of subgraphs of $G$ that look like $K_{1,2}$ (a "cherry"). Certainly if we (double) count those, considering a vertice in the center of the cherry, we get:
>
> $$k=\sum_{v\in V}\binom{\text{deg}(v)}{2}$$
>
> Now if we don't allow squares a pair of vertices $\{v,w\}$ can be
> endpoints of only one cherry, otherwise we would have a cycle,
> therefore
>
> $$\binom{n}{2} \geq k=\sum_{v\in V}\binom{\text{deg}(v)}{2}$$
>
> Then due to convexity of $\binom{x}{2}$ and the Jensen-Inequality one
> might conclude now that $m \leq \frac{1}{4} \cdot \left(\sqrt{n^2 (4n-3)}+n\right) $.

This is a link to [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) in case you don't know it.

Edit: As the operator asked for more details:

Define $\varphi(x):=\binom{n}{2}$, it is easy to see that $\varphi$ is convex. Therefore we have that

$$\varphi\left(\frac{\sum x_i}{n}\right) \le \frac{\sum \varphi (x_i)}{n} \iff \sum \varphi (x_i) \geq n\cdot \varphi\left(\frac{\sum x_i}{n}\right)$$

And therefore

$$\binom{n}{2} \geq \sum_{v\in V}\binom{\text{deg}(v)}{2} \geq n\cdot \binom{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{v\in V}\text{deg}(v)}{2}=n\cdot\binom{\frac{2m}{n}}{2}$$

Because the sum over all degrees of the nodes corresponds to twice the amount of edges. Expanding the binomial on both sides yields your result.

Comment: I know Jensen's function, but would you please show me how to apply it here? every time I use it on this question I get $m\le \frac{n}{4}(1+2\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: @goodarzmehr I tried to be a bit more explicit. I hope you understand it now.

Comment: now I undrestand, thanks a lot :)

Comment: no problem :P, good that you understood it

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ denote the set of edges of $V$. Let $d(v)$ denote the degree of $v\in V$. Let $F$ denote the set
$$F=\{(u,v,w):(u,v),(u,w)\in E; v\neq w\}$$
Now, note that each vertex $u$ contributes $d(u)(d(u)-1)$ elements to $F$ since this is the number of choices for $v$ and $w$ among the neighbors of $u$. So,
$$|F|=\sum_{u\in V}d(u)(d(u)-1)$$
Also, given an ordered pair $(v,w)$ of vertices, there is atmost one choice of $u$ since we are trying to avoid $C_4$. So,
$$|F|\leq n(n-1)$$
So, combining these two,
\begin{align*}
    n(n-1)&\geq \sum_{u\in V} d(u)^2-\sum_{u\in V} d(u)\\
    &\geq \frac 1n\left(\sum_{u\in V} d(u)\right)^2-\sum_{u\in V} d(u)\;\;\text{[Cauchy Schwarz]}\\
    &=\frac{\left(2|E|\right)^2}{n}-2|E|
\end{align*}
So,
$$4|E|^2-2n|E|-n^2(n-1)\leq 0$$
The solution to this quadratic yields
$$|E|\leq \frac n4\left(1+\sqrt{4n-3}\right)$$