# If the degree of every vertex in a graph on $n$ vertices is greater than $(1+ \sqrt{4n-3})/2$, then the graph contains a cycle of length $4$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Show that if the degree of every vertex in a graph on $n$ vertices is greater than $\frac{1+ \sqrt{4n-3}}{2}$, then the graph contains a cycle of length $4$.

This is a problem in extremal combinatorics, but I have no idea how to proceed as I am quite new to the topic.

Comment: This is Reiman's theorem(see I. Reiman, Über ein Problem von K. Zarankiewicz, Acta. Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar. 9 (1958) 269–273). To prove, calculate in two different ways the size of the set $X=\{u,v,w\}$, where $uv$ and $uw$ are edges.

Comment: As a starting point, can you write down the inequality, quadratic in degree $d$ involving $n$. Hint: think about either the quadratic formula or [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) for coefficients of a polynomial in terms of its roots.

Comment: Very closely related question (possibly a duplicate): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89644/graph-avoiding-cycle-of-length-4/