# Estimate $\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q}\deg(x)(\deg(x)-1)$ in the bipartite graph with no 4-cycles

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields, bipartite-graphs

Consider a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and polynomials $g(x),h(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_q.$ Define
$$
f(x,y)=xy+g(x)+h(y)\quad\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{F}_q\times\mathbb{F}_q,
$$
$$
N(x)=\left\{y\in\mathbb{F}_q:~f(x,y)=0\right\}.
$$
Want to **prove** that $$\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q}|N(x)|(|N(x)|-1)\leqslant q(q-1).$$
I **have** that:

1. Since
   \begin{align*}
   f(x_1,y_1)+f(x_2,y_2)-f(x_1,y_2)-f(x_2,y_1)&=x_1y_1+x_2y_2-x_1y_2-x_2y_1
   \\
   &=(x_1-x_2)(y_1-y_2),
   \end{align*}
   it is seen that
   $$
   \left(x_1\neq x_2,~y_1\neq y_2\right)\Rightarrow \left(y_1\notin N(x_1) \vee y_1\notin N(x_2) \vee y_2\notin N(x_1)\vee y_2\notin N(x_2)\right).
   $$
2. Consider the undirected bipartite graph $K_{q,q}$ with classes $X=\left\{x\in\mathbb{F}_q\right\},~Y=\left\{y\in\mathbb{F}_q\right\}$ and ($(x,y)$ is edge iff $y\in N(x)$). From the first statement I see that such graph has no 4-cycles. The problem in these therms (as I see) is to prove the estimate
   $$
   \sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q}\deg(x)(\deg(x)-1)\leqslant q(q-1).
   $$
   Also it is known that $\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q}\deg(x)$ is the number of edges in $K_{q,q}.$

Comment: Check this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89644/graph-avoiding-cycle-of-length-4

Comment: In short, the absence of 4-cycles means that for each pait of vertices $u$ and $v$ there is at most one vertex $w$ such that $uw$ and $vw$ are edges of the graph.

Comment: Thank you very much!